# How can I stop drag just in one direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leap-motion

I'm workin' with `Leap Motion`, and currently I'm developing a `draggable` map, utilizing `_grab` function. To avoid that users `_grab/drag_` the map behind its limit, I need to stop the movement just in one (or two) direction(s);
i.e., if top position of map reach value 0, I need to stop the possibility to move on y axes but just on one direction (that drag map beyond 0).
Actually I have the check on position, and stop (all) the move, but it isn't good...

Comment: Do you have an example and errors/debugging information?

Comment: I haven't errors, but I need to stop drag just for one or two directions.
Actually, I come out to stop **all** move, not just the desired...